# Laravel backpack admin fetching over https rather than http

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a laravel 7 app running in a dokku container that is secured with letsencrypt. My RESTful/graph endpoints are correctly served securely but my admin backend is trying to load insecure assets over http.

I've set the following environment variables:

- APP_ENV=production
- APP_URL=https://example.com
- APP_URI=https://example.com
- ASSET_URL=https://example.com

I've also tried to enforce https through `routes/web.php`:

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}/
```

No matter what, laravel backpack is loading assets through `http://example.com/...` thus leading to a mixed-content error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `secure_asset('...')`

BTW, `URL::forceScheme('https');` also works, may be you have other mistake in provider.

Comment: the thing is, the AJAX calls backpack makes are also to http:// (eg, http://example.com/admin/post/search)

Comment: Please double check current protocol in browser. And double check your URL::forceScheme('https'); is running this code should be in AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: Ok! Adding `Url::forceScheme('https')` to `AppServiceProvider.php` did the trick, thank you :)